# Unable to push to git from android studio

Tags: git, android-studio

Previously, I was able to pull and push changes to github repositories directly from android studio terminal. But these days git add . and commit works fine but when i try to push to git repository using **git push origin master**, I get an error **git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.**.

Comment: which comman do you type into the console to push?

Comment: git push origin master

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

If that doesn't work, check if you are using the correct git executable. It may be a problem with the `path` environment variable.

Comment: i am working with windows 10

Comment: I think the easiest way to try to solve the problem is to reinstall git.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then try find `git-remote-https.exe` or `git.exe` executable files and add containing folder in `path` environment variable. I think it would help